# Why should we avoid using rescue in its modifier form?

Tags: ruby, error-handling

I will define value. But this value may be in value of key of hash. I will use **rescue** for define value is nil if this keys is not exist.
for example

`foo = bar[:a][:b][:c] rescue nil`

But in practice tell me bad style because me using rescue in its modifier form. I will change logic to use check three condition.

`foo = bar[:a][:b][:c] if bar.key?(:a) && bar[:a].key?(:b) && bar[:a][:b].key?(:c)`

I really would like to know why should we avoid using rescue in its modifier form?

Comment: It is worthwhile noting that while it is bad style, there are legitimate uses for it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Why should we avoid using rescue in its modifier form in rails?

Firstly, because it hides *all* errors, including the ones you expect and the ones you don't, and a blanket `rescue` doesn't make it clear to future readers of your code *which* errors were expected or unexpected. This might not be a problem *now*, with a simple `foo[:a][:b][:c]`, but at any given point in time somebody might modify that statement to read `foo[:a][:b][some_method]` and suddenly any errors that *should* bubble out of `some_method` are also swallowed.

Secondly, there is usually a better less all-encompassing solution that is more explicitly designed to handle only the error you intend to ignore: A missing index or a `nil` return value.

In your case, the alternative is *not* the massive `if && && &&` you're suggesting. For a hash, you can use either [`dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig), which has all the benefits of `rescue` without swallowing every type of exception that could be raised:

```
foo = bar.dig(:a, :b, :c)
```

Similarly, for chained method invocations, you can use `try` (in Rails) or the safe navigation operator (in Ruby 2.3):

```
foo = bar.try(:a).try(:b).try(:c)
# or
foo = bar&.a&.b&.c
```

Comment: IMHO it is worth noting that raising an exception is a pretty expensive operation. Returning `nil` by using one of the alternatives is usually way faster in cases in which a key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

The longer form is more safe, I wouldn't use the short version in production unless there is no other way.
Whether you use checks or an exeption to avoid or catch errors depends on the situation. Exeptions are costly in processor time, so do your benchmarks for time consuming methods, on the other hand doing a lot of checks and still not being sure is perhaps worse.
If the readability of my code would be lost by doing a lot of checks and speed isn't a factor I use begin .. rescue or def .. rescue but in that case you are better to rescue a known exception like this

```
begin  
  # -  
  raise "another exception"
rescue SyntaxError 
  # -  
rescue => exception
  @errors += 1
  log exception
  log exception.backtrace  
end
```

Which gives

```
another exception
C:/.../test.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Always catch the kind of exception and put or better log it, I also use it to raise a variable @errors which is logged for all of my scripts and monitored by a separate tool.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid

```
... rescue ...
```

for the same reason as

```
begin
  ...
rescue
  ...
end
```

Neither specifies an exception class and are thus silently skipping over ALL errors rather than just the one that you expect. You should always be as specific as possible when rescuing errors.

Also there is a big cost to creating an exception.

When you raise an exception the backtrace is filled in, and in Rails that means creating 500 to 1000 strings with filenames and line numbers because Rails tends to have a deep call stack. So if you put your `rescue nil` inside a loop it may easily end up creating thousands of string objects that are never used, and with Ruby's abysmal garbage collection this will affect your performance.

Hence when possible try to use alternatives that don't raise exception

```
foo = bar.dig(:a, :b, :c)
```

Answer (score 2):

A typical example as to why it is a bad idea :

```
foo = ban[:a][:b][:c] rescue nil
```

You could lose a lot of time checking that `bar` really has `{a: {b: {c: :something}}}` and wondering why `foo` is `nil` : there's a typo, and `rescue nil` hides it.

For alternatives, see @meagar's good answer.