# Short alternative to ternary and rescue in modifier form

Tags: ruby, rescue

When loading files, I used to do some variant of:

```
first_file = "#{__dir__}/first_file.txt"
first_data = File.exist?(first_file) ? File.readlines(first_file) : []

second_file = "#{__dir__}/second_file.yaml"
second_data = File.exist?(second_file) ? YAML.load_file(second_file) : {}
```

That always sat a bit wrong with me. Needing the check to see if the file exists is something that *needs* to be there, but what I really care about is what comes after.

Eventually I discovered inline `rescue`, and started doing it like this:

```
first_file = "#{__dir__}/first_file.txt"
first_data = File.readlines(firs_file) rescue []

second_file = "#{__dir__}/second_file.yaml"
second_data = YAML.load_file(second_file) rescue {}
```

This to me is way clearer — try to this thing you really want, and if you can’t do this other thing that is exactly the fallback you want. It’s both shorter and clearer than the ternary.

But everywhere I look the same advice to [avoid `rescue` in modifier form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526504/why-should-we-avoid-using-rescue-in-its-modifier-form) is repeated. I understand why that is: that it can hide errors we weren’t predicting.

If I could define `Errno::ENOENT` as the error to `rescue` from in the inline form, I would. But as far as I can tell, inline `rescue` can’t specify what error to rescue from.

So what is the alternative? What can I do that is as short and clear as the inline `rescue`, but without the disadvantage?

Comment: Go back to your old way.

Comment: I agree with Sergio, clever one liners are not so readable many times. Just create some helper methods.

Comment: I think I was clear why I don’t want to go back to the old way. If the only argument is “go back to the old way”, might as well just stick with the new.

Answer (score 2):

If I was *really* concerned about readability of those lines, I'd create some helper methods.

```
def read_with_fallback(filename, fallback)
  File.exist?(filename) ? yield(File.open(filename)) : fallback
end

def safe_read_lines(filename)
  read_with_fallback(first_file, []) {|file| file.readlines }
end

def safe_read_yaml(filename)
  read_with_fallback(second_file, {}) {|file| YAML.parse(file.read) }
end

first_file = "#{__dir__}/first_file.txt"
first_data = safe_read_lines(first_file)

second_file = "#{__dir__}/second_file.yaml"
second_data = safe_read_yaml(second_file)
```

But if I had just one or two of those and didn't have to repeat them in every other method, then I wouldn't bother. Your first form is "good enough".

Comment: “I'd create some helper methods”—my eyes are bleeding :) Do you _really_ think, that mysterious `safe_read_lines` for future readers of this code (who accomplished at least 1st level in ruby) is more readable, than `File.readlines(firs_file) rescue []`?

Comment: @mudasobwa: naming could be improved, undoubtedly. But yes, I do believe that this concept of "try your best at reading this yaml file" reads better when given a name. Higher level of abstraction. `YAML.load_file(second_file) rescue {}` - this is expressed with at least 4 "bits" of information, when in reality it's just one, "read yaml file". Why compile code in your head. trying to infer the _meaning_ of the code when you can avoid it? Also, read the last part :)

Comment: @mudasobwa: also there's nothing "mysterious" about that method. Its definition is one keystroke away (for those with  powered editors) :)

Comment: @user137369 ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯